# "Warning: Trying to remove a child that doesn't exist" Why am I getting this warning in React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm getting a warning in React Native that I've narrowed down to one line and I've no clue why.

I've built a helper function to animate colors and values in a series like:

```
animate([this, "textColor", 250, "#fff1cc"]);
animate([this, "rise", 250, 25], [this, "rise", 250, 0]);
```

And that function is pretty simple, note the commented line causing the error:

```
// React Modules

import { Animated } from "react-native";

// Export

export default function func() {
  step(0, arguments);
}

// Extras

function step(index, args, delay = 0) {
  if (args[index]) {
    let argument = args[index];
    index++;
    handle(argument, delay, () => {
      step(index, args);
    });
  }
}

function handle(argument, delay = 0, callback) {
  let that = argument[0];
  let label = argument[1];
  let duration = argument[2];
  let endColor = argument[3];
  let startColor = argument[4];
  if (!that.interpolations) {
    that.interpolations = {};
  }
  if (!that.animations) {
    that.animations = {};
  }
  if (!that.animations[label]) {
    that.animations[label] = new Animated.Value(0);
  }
  if (typeof endColor == "string") {
    if (!startColor) {
      if (that.interpolations[label]) {
        startColor = JSON.stringify(that.interpolations[label]);
      } else {
        startColor = "#ffffff";
      }
    }
    that.interpolations[label] = that.animations[label].interpolate({
      inputRange: [0, 100],
      outputRange: [startColor, endColor]
    });
    startValue = 0;
    endValue = 100;
  } else {
    startValue = startColor || that.animations[label] || 0;
    // setting this to that.animations[label] causes the warning
    endValue = endColor;
  }
  Animated.timing(that.animations[label], { // warning triggered when
  // Animated.timing() executes while startValue is set to that.animations[label]
    toValue: startValue, 
    duration: 0
  }).start();
  Animated.timing(that.animations[label], {
    toValue: endValue,
    duration: duration || 500
  }).start(callback);
}
```

Other than that warning, the code works perfectly as expected. I'd hate to just ignore a warning I don't understand though. Should I report this as a bug to the React Native repo, or is the warning warranted? [Stack trace, for those interested.](https://gist.github.com/viziionary/51895c88190003d6c39bb0543fcd2d3f)

Comment: If anyone's interested in the stack trace, [here you have it](https://gist.github.com/viziionary/51895c88190003d6c39bb0543fcd2d3f)

Comment: Also the stack trace mentions the file `bottom-button.js:35:12` where animate is called, [here's that file](https://gist.github.com/viziionary/72902997849ee43b87fada5f5b53007b) in case relevant.

Comment: is that.animations[label] storing a valid value ?

Comment: @colxi I'll double check now

Comment: Yes @colxi the value is always a number, never undefined

Comment: startValue and endValue are not properly declared at the begining of the function, using 'let', any change if you fix that ?

Comment: @colxi oops, thanks, and no change. I'll update the code soon but am on mobile rn.

Comment: Maybe you should move calls to `animate` from constructor to `componentDidMount`?

Comment: @SergeSeredenko That cant work because I'm using the animate calls with 0 animation time to originally set the animated values, so they have to be called in the constructor or those styles fail I believe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I am not sure one hundred percent because I couldn't reproduce your error. Following your stack trace, in [L193](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/daa7c78055857cd2d9ea650de0c4b0f72d3f2acf/Libraries/Animated/src/AnimatedImplementation.js#L193) we have:

```
singleValue.stopTracking();
```

This has a chain of operations that try to untrack the Animated value.

It treats the value passed to `Animated.timing` as an `AnimatedValue` and then it reaches the point where `AnimatedWithChildren` try to detach the children `Value` nodes of your animation. The only reason I have find is that the value you have send is not a [Animated Value](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/daa7c78055857cd2d9ea650de0c4b0f72d3f2acf/Libraries/Animated/src/nodes/AnimatedValue.js) but rather a plain primitive.

So if you follow any example of the [official documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animations#animated-api), you will see that `startValue` should be `new Animated.Value(0)` instead of `0`. So the tracking, the detaching and all the animated flow, works properly over this value.

Only in part of your application, you will assign `that.animations[label]`, that is a `new Animated.Value`, but in other ones you are directly assigning a integer like in `startValue = 0;`

Comment: I'll check this out and get back to you. Maybe that's it

Comment: Perfect, hopefully is only that

Comment: Hej @johndoe, just wanted to know if this solved your problem